# Can you give me an example of metonymy using slang?

Tags: slang

Can you use slang in an example of metonymy?  For example,  If I say, "his jacket is crispy" (crispy meaning really stylish).  Or "put some panties on that window" (meaning roll that window up).  I know that "lend a hand" or "people don't make it in Hollywood" are examples of metonymy, but it got me wondering about slang and if it too is metonymy.  If my examples are horrible which they probably are (I'm just throwing something out there), can you give me an example of metonymy using slang (any type of slang).

Comment: "Lend a hand" and might have metonomic elements, "people don't make it in Hollywood" certainly does not; both are just "idioms" or "colloquial expressions".

Comment: @Carly ‘Hollywood’ is used metonymically for the movie industry here, rather than referring to the place itself, so it does have a metonymic element.

Comment: The question is ambiguous whether the word 'slang' (to refer to a particular group's language) can be an example of 'metonymy' or a slang word or an expression (because of its being a slang) can be accepted as metonymic.

Comment: I didn't mean for it to be ambiguous.  I guess I was just trying to find a connection between my culture's slang and metonymy.  I wanted to find a better example because honestly the example lend a hand or referring to a car as wheels  are obvious examples of metonymy.  I was just trying to find a more challenging example in my everyday language.

Comment: Actually I think wheels is an example of synecdoche.  But you get my point.

Comment: It's not always easy to know why people use slang as they do. But my students say that something is "chalk" to mean that it's over, perhaps because at crime scenes a chalk outline shows where a human body lay until it was removed. That's a sort of metonymy, I think.

Comment: It's also hard to say when something moves from being slang to being just informal. Think of "suits" meaning "professionals in charge", as in "Look out, here come the suits". Is that slang, or just informal?

Answer (score 0):

Your examples might not be the best examples of metonomy:

**me·ton·y·my**
*NOUN*

> the substitution of the name of an attribute or adjunct for that of the thing meant, for example suit for business executive, or the track for horse racing.

It means using one part of a thing to refer to a whole like, like calling a *car* as "wheels," or a *dog* as "chompers" (in reference to its teeth).

So, if "slang" is an example of metonomy, would depend on the slang. Neither of your examples would therefore qualify.

Comment: Reference to a part for the whole is one type of metonymy, namely synechdoche. Metonymy also includes reference to other types of attributes, not just part-to-whole. E.g., a track is not *part* of a horse race, and a suit is not *part* of a business executive; but both tracks and suits are adjuncts *associated with* horse races and business executives, respectively. This broader sense is metonymy.